# Why do i get different object ID's when appending same object to different list in python OOP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have  deposit, withdraw and transfer methods in my OOP banking app that seems to be printing correct values, although if I remove the **repr** method it shows that 1 ID is not identical.

EDIT: My other classes, not sure if relevant here:

```
class PersonError(Exception):
    """Person error."""
    pass


class TransactionError(Exception):
    """Transaction error."""
    pass


class Person:
    """Person class."""

    def __init__(self, first_name: str, last_name: str, age: int):
        """
        Person constructor.

        :param first_name: first name
        :param last_name: last name
        :param age: age, must be greater than 0
        """
        if not first_name or not last_name:
            raise PersonError
        else:
            self.first_name = first_name
            self.last_name = last_name

        self.bank_account = None
        if age <= 0:
            raise PersonError
        else:
            self._age = age

    @property
    def full_name(self) -> str:
        """Get person's full name. Combination of first and last name."""
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    @property
    def age(self) -> int:
        """Get person's age."""
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value: int):
        """Set person's age. Must be greater than 0."""
        if value <= 0:
            raise PersonError
        else:
            self._age = value

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        """
        Person representation.

        :return: person's full name
        """
        return self.full_name


class Bank:
    """Bank class."""

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        """
        Bank constructor.

        :param name: name of the bank
        """
        self.name = name
        self.customers = []
        self.transactions = []


    def add_customer(self, person: Person) -> bool:
        """
        Add customer to bank.

        :param person: person object
        :return: was customer successfully added
        """
        if person not in self.customers:
            self.customers.append(person)
            person.bank_account = Account(0, person, bank)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def remove_customer(self, person: Person) -> bool:
        """
        Remove customer from bank.

        :param person: person object
        :return: was customer successfully removed
        """
        if person in self.customers:
            self.customers.remove(person)
            person.bank_account = None
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        """
        Bank representation.

        :return: name of the bank
        """
        return self.name


class Transaction:
    """Transaction class."""

    def __init__(self, amount: float, date: datetime.date, sender_account: 'Account', receiver_account: 'Account',
                 is_from_atm: bool):
        """
        Transaction constructor.

        :param amount: value
        :param date: date of the transaction
        :param sender_account: sender's object
        :param receiver_account: receiver's object
        :param is_from_atm: is transaction from atm
        """
        self.is_from_atm = is_from_atm
        self.receiver_account = receiver_account
        self.sender_account = sender_account
        self.date = date
        self.amount = amount

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        """
        Transaction representation.

        :rtype: object's values displayed in a nice format
        """
        if self.is_from_atm is True:
            return f"({self.amount} €) ATM"
        elif self.is_from_atm is False:
            return f"({self.amount} €) {self.sender_account.person} -> {self.receiver_account.person}"
```

My methods:

```
class Account:
    """Account class."""

    def __init__(self, balance: float, person: Person, bank: 'Bank'):
        """
        Account constructor.

        :param balance: initial account balance
        :param person: person object
        :param bank: bank object
        """
        self.bank = bank
        self.person = person
        self._balance = balance
        self.number = f"EE{randint(111111111111111111, 999999999999999999)}"
        self.transactions = []

    @property
    def balance(self) -> float:
        """Get account's balance."""
        return self._balance

    def deposit(self, amount: float, is_from_atm: bool = True):
        """Deposit money to account."""
        if amount <= 0:
            raise TransactionError
        elif is_from_atm is True:
            t = Transaction(amount, date=datetime.date.today(), sender_account=self, receiver_account=self, is_from_atm=True)
            self._balance = self._balance + amount
            self.transactions.append(t)
            bank.transactions.append(t)
        elif is_from_atm is False:

            self._balance = self._balance + amount

    def withdraw(self, amount: float, is_from_atm: bool = True):
        """Withdraw money from account."""
        if amount <= 0 or amount > self._balance:
            raise TransactionError
        elif is_from_atm is True:
            t = Transaction(-amount, date=datetime.date.today(), sender_account=self, receiver_account=self, is_from_atm=True)
            self._balance = self._balance - amount
            self.transactions.append(t)
            bank.transactions.append(t)
        elif is_from_atm is False:

            self._balance = self._balance - amount

    def transfer(self, amount: float, receiver_account: 'Account'):
        """Transfer money from one account to another."""
        fee = 5
        if receiver_account == self:
            raise TransactionError
        elif (self._balance - fee - amount) < 0:
            raise TransactionError
        elif receiver_account.bank != self.bank and amount >= 0:
            t = Transaction(amount, datetime.date.today(), sender_account=self, receiver_account=receiver_account,
                            is_from_atm=False)
            self._balance = self._balance - amount - fee
            self.transactions.append(t)
            self.bank.transactions.append(t)

            t = Transaction(amount, datetime.date.today(), sender_account=self, receiver_account=receiver_account,
                            is_from_atm=False)
            receiver_account._balance = receiver_account._balance + amount
            receiver_account.transactions.append(t)
            receiver_account.bank.transactions.append(t)
        elif receiver_account.bank == self.bank and amount >= 0:
            t = Transaction(amount, datetime.date.today(), sender_account=self, receiver_account=receiver_account,
                            is_from_atm=False)
            self._balance = self._balance - amount
            self.transactions.append(t)
            self.bank.transactions.append(t)

            t = Transaction(amount, datetime.date.today(), sender_account=self, receiver_account=receiver_account,
                            is_from_atm=False)
            receiver_account._balance = receiver_account._balance + amount
            receiver_account.transactions.append(t)
```

If name is main :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    person = Person("Ago", "Luberg", 100)
    
    bank = Bank("TalBank")
    bank.add_customer(person)
    a1 = person.bank_account

    person2 = Person("Mati", "Maal", 90)
    bank.add_customer(person2)
    a2 = person2.bank_account
    
    a1.deposit(100)
    a2.deposit(100)
    a1.withdraw(10)
    a2.withdraw(50)
    a1.transfer(10, a2)
    
    
    print(a1.transactions)  # [(100 €) ATM, (-10 €) ATM, (10 €) Ago Luberg -> Mati Maal]
    print(a2.transactions)  # [(100 €) ATM, (-50 €) ATM, (10 €) Ago Luberg -> Mati Maal]
    print(bank.transactions)
    # [(100 €) ATM, (100 €) ATM, (-10 €) ATM, (-50 €) ATM, (10 €) Ago Luberg -> Mati Maal]
```

My output without **repr** when printing transactions:

```
1. person1 transactions [<__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF4F0>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF490>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF340>]
2. person2 transactions [<__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF520>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF400>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF2B0>]
3. bank transactions(person1 + person2 transactions) [<__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF4F0>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF520>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF490>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF400>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF340>]
```

Expected output without **repr** method:

```
1. person1 transactions [<__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF4F0>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF490>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF340>]
2. person2 transactions [<__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF520>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF400>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF340>]
3. bank transactions(person1 + person2 transactions) [<__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF4F0>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF520>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF490>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF400>, <__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000024AE1ACF340>]
```

My question is why is the last transaction object in person2 transactions not identical to the last transaction in person1 and bank transactions although with **repr** method they are identical.

Output with **repr** method :

```
[(100 €) ATM, (-10 €) ATM, (10 €) Ago Luberg -> Mati Maal]
[(100 €) ATM, (-50 €) ATM, (10 €) Ago Luberg -> Mati Maal]
[(100 €) ATM, (100 €) ATM, (-10 €) ATM, (-50 €) ATM, (10 €) Ago Luberg -> Mati Maal]
```

Thanks in advance to whomever wishes to contribute with their help!
Crimson.

Comment: Why do you assume the identity should be the same? The ``__repr__`` methods outputs an arbitrary string. It has no bearing on object identity.

Comment: Also, *strongly* consider to build a [mcve] – emphasis on minimal. This "issue" can be shown in a dozen lines of code. There is no need to throw almost 250 lines of code at people.

Comment: I assume the identity should be the same, since I am appending the exact same object in my transfer method within Account class. t = Transaction(etc). From my understanding they should be identical

Comment: I was unsure if i could build a minimal reproducdible example of this, my apologies. I am quite new to Python and SO community, thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this portion of the code:

```
elif receiver_account.bank != self.bank and amount >= 0:
            t = Transaction(amount, datetime.date.today(), sender_account=self, receiver_account=receiver_account,
                            is_from_atm=False)
            self._balance = self._balance - amount - fee
            self.transactions.append(t)
            self.bank.transactions.append(t)

            t = Transaction(amount, datetime.date.today(), sender_account=self, receiver_account=receiver_account,
                            is_from_atm=False)
            receiver_account._balance = receiver_account._balance + amount
            receiver_account.transactions.append(t)
            receiver_account.bank.transactions.append(t)
```

You are declaring `t` twice: declaring it one time, then appending it to `self.transactions`, then declaring it another time (so it becomes equal to another object reference) and appending it to `receiver_account`. So `t` the first time and the second time is not the same object.

Removing the second declaration of `t` should give your expected result.

Comment: Should I remove the entire t = Transaction or just the t in front of Transaction? Thanks in regards.

Comment: The entire (second) line, as you do not need two different objects holding the same value

Comment: Thank you kind sir, before designating this as the best answer, would you be willing to tell me as to why this code could be printing a NameError: name 'bank' is not defined? Best regards, Crimson